# Replacing an item in a list

Tags: python, list, replace

I am facing difficulty in replacing an item in a list. How do I go about doing it?
Below is my code. Here I need to replace the guessed letter if it matches with the chosen_word's letter.

```py
import random
word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower
display = []
for letter in chosen_word:
  display.append("_")
print(display)
```

Comment: First call `lower()`. At the moment `guess` is a function (the function lower) rather than a string. Second, append the letter if it is equal to your guess otherwise append the underscore `display.append(letter if letter == guess else "_")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chosen_word.replace(guess, "_")` - e.g. if chosen_word is `baboon` and guess is `b`, this will output `_a_oon`.

In your current code, you don't condition on `guess` so there is no interaction between `guess` and `chosen_word`.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `if` statement inside of the `for` loop to check if `letter` is equal to `guess`. If it is, you append it to `display`. Otherwise, you append an underscore `"_"` to `display`.

```
for letter in chosen_word:
    if letter == guess:
        display.append(letter)
    else:
        display.append("_")
print(display)
```

See [w3schools page on if statements](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_if_statement.asp)

Also, change `input("Guess a letter: ").lower` to `input("Guess a letter: ").lower() to call the method